# Date picker icon placed on left side within input field

Tags: css, angular, datepicker, icons

i would like to put the calender icon of the left side on the box, not on the right, where it is by default. can somebody help me with this please? i used the "normal" angular datepicker, as you can see below:

```
<input (dateChange)="changePatDate($event)" [max]="this.maxDate" 
       matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" 
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker startView="multi-year" #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

i would like it to look more like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDRU5.png

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to change matSuffix to matPrefix